# Vaadin can't parse its Security Key after upgrading to 7.5.3

Tags: json, vaadin, vaadin7, uidl

I have a weird problem after upgrading Vaadin in my application from 7.1.8 to 7.5.3.

My login servlet cannot process any requests due to an invalid, what I think it is, Vaadin's security key.

Vaadin now uses elemental.json and I'm getting an error when the used interacts with the application for the first time.

I've browsed SO and Vaadin forums and I seem to be the only with the problem :(

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the stack

> 14:09:31,232 SEVERE [UidlRequestHandler:103] [] Error writing JSON to response
>   elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid number literal: 8575f881-3226-47e0-b675-3c4a309f9373
>       at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getNumberForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:284)
>       at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getValueForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:307)
>       at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.nextValue(JsonTokenizer.java:175)
>       at elemental.json.impl.JreJsonFactory.parse(JreJsonFactory.java:64)
>       at elemental.json.impl.JsonUtil.parse(JsonUtil.java:200)
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler$RpcRequest.(ServerRpcHandler.java:82)
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:194)
>       at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:95)
>       at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
>       at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
>       at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
>       at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:77)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)

Comment: Can you please add some code related to this? The login process in your servlet should be usefull here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when upgrading from Vaadin 7.1.11 to 7.5.3.

Do you use vaadin-client-7.5.3 / Add-ons and compile your own Widgetsets (and not only use vaadin-client-compiled-7.5.3)?

I could solve the issue by re-compiling my Client-side modules (Vaadin Client Widgetsets and Vaadin Addons Widgetsets) with the Vaadin Client Compiler Version 7.5.3.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That was it! I initially performed the recompilation of the client side, but due to a complex structure of my application (OSGi) I wasn't using the new Vaadin version at that exact moment.